How can you check the type of a picture is pasted on a slide in PowerPoint?
I wrote this code to id format a picture pasted in PowerPoint.  However, it just returns that it's a picture -- not the format.  I need to know the format of the picture -- if it's a PNG, JPG, etc. -- to do correct handling
    Dim osh As Shape
    Set osh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    MsgBox osh.Type 
End Sub

Thanks in advance!

Once it's pasted into PowerPoint, it's in PowerPoint's control, which is why it's just a picture. What do you need to handle? What specifically does correct handling mean?

Thanks @KenWhite - I need to be able to check if it's the correct picture time to be able to manipulate some picture settings that are available to some but not other image types.

To determine the underlying picture type, you'd have to unzip the PPTX file and view the files in the \media folder. And work out how to relate those to the images on the individual slides (I'm guessing by looking at the rels tables)

@SteveRindsberg thank you - didn't think it would be that complicated

Why do you need to know the exact type? What kind of handling do you need to carry out? If you just need to distinguish between raster and vector images, you could try ungrouping to see if it throws an error. You can't ungroup raster images.

@SteveRindsberg Hi, I wanted to be able to add a shape to the image with certain properties, name, size, type, link to original image, etc.

By poking around in the XML, you could probably retrieve the size and type of the images (as stored in the PPTX file; that might not be the same as the originally inserted image files). The picture will have a shape name in PPT; that's easy enough to retrieve: its .Name property will give you that. But that's likely to be something "informative" like "Picture12". IF the image was inserted as a link, you can get the path\name of original image (if available) and from that, the image's size/type etc. But by default, PPT embeds images rather than linking them.

a quick way could be to clone the file and change its extension to .zip as Steve suggested, then with 7Zip (much better for this purpose than Winzip) you could just navigate the archive and find the information you are looking for (all through code).
